# Estimating fit parameter uncertainty when $\chi^2$ is severely non-Gaussian

Tags: least-squares, goodness-of-fit

## The Context

I am trying to make a comparison between two models in theoretical
physics:

- Model $A$ is a theoretically exact means of calculating a function
  $f(x)$, where $x$ is a continuous variable. This model depends only on a physical quantity $\alpha$. If one knows $\alpha$, one can calculate an exact $f(x;\alpha)$.
- Model $B$ is an approximate theory for $f(x)$ which depends instead
  on a tunable parameter $\beta$. For any value of $\beta$, one can
  calculate an estimate $\hat f(x;\beta)$.

Model $B$ is founded on the assumption that for small values of $\alpha
$, the true $f(x;\alpha)$ can be very well approximated by $\hat f(x;
\beta)$ for some value of $\beta$. **My ultimate aim is to determine the range of $\alpha$ where this assumption holds.**

## The Method

The theories that give $f$ and $\hat f$ must be evaluated numerically, so in practice I have tabulated values of $f$ and $\hat f$ at several points $x_i$.

My method is a naive $\chi^2$ goodness-of-fit approach:

1. For a given $\alpha$, compute $f_i=f(x_i;\alpha)$. This plays the role of my "measured" data, with assumed negligible measurement error.
2. Compute $\hat f(x_i,\beta)$ across a sufficiently wide, well-resolved range of $\beta$ values.
3. For each value of $\beta$, compute
   $$
   \chi^2(\beta) = \int dx |f(x;\alpha) - \hat f(x;\beta)|^2
   $$
   by some quadrature rule. Let's assume I'm using sufficiently many $x_i$ that errors in the integral are negligible.
4. Find the best-fit $\beta_*$ from the minimum of $\chi^2$.
5. Estimate the uncertainty in $\beta_*$ from $\sigma_\beta^2 = 2\left(\frac{\partial^2 \chi^2}{\partial \beta^2}\right)^{-1}$ at $\beta_*$

In practice, I do the last two steps by finding the parabola that passes through the three points of my tabulated $\chi^2(\beta)$ that surround the minimum.

## The Results

In each of the plots below, the black line is $\chi^2(\beta)$, the pink parabola is the fit about the minimum, and the vertical dotted line marks the optimal $\beta$. The barely visible black crosses mark the points used to determine the parabola.

[image: small alpha, large uncertainty][image: large alpha, small uncertainty]

For small $\alpha$ - when I should expect my fitted $\hat f(x;\beta_*)$ to be very good - I indeed find a very small $\chi^2$. However, the curvature of $\chi^2$ immediately about its minimum is incredibly shallow, giving a large uncertainty in $\beta_*$.

In contrast, at large $\alpha$ - large enough that the assumptions behind Model $B$ should fail - the minimum $\chi^2$ is larger. I take this as a reflection that the "best" fit is no longer as good as it was when $\alpha$ was small. However, the curvature about $\beta_*$ is much tighter, implying that in this case the fit is poorer, but more certain?

The main feature that catches my interest is the fact that $\chi^2$ is nearly constant when $\beta$ is small; the distribution of $\chi^2$ is not approximately Gaussian, and thus **my estimated uncertainty in $\beta_*$ is not meaningful when $\beta_*$ is small.**

After all this, I'm led to...

## The Question

How can I meaningfully estimate the uncertainty in my fit parameter $\beta$?

Comment: Is there any stochastic, i.e., random about your problem?  Is  $f(x;\alpha)$ deterministic? f so, I think you're barking up the wrong tree with a statistical approach, and the problem is "just" an approximation/numerical analysis problem. You could approach Model B as an optimization problem using appropriate "loss" function, such as maximizing range of $\alpha$ subject to upper bound on worst case approximation error (infinity norm), or minimizing worst case approximation error subject to range of $\alpha$ exceeding some minimum value. If there's a stochastic aspect, describe it more clearly.

Comment: If this is a deterministic approximation problem,then if you (still) need help, it's more appropriate at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Right, there is no stochastic nature to my "data" from either Model. I did consider posting to SciComp, but I thought that problems of this nature would be a standard (or at least solved) problem in statistics.

Comment: This is not a statistics problem. It is an approximation problem. I gave an outline of a possible approach (with a couple of variations) in my first comment above, but that is predicated on your having a candidate functional form for the approximation for which you want to determine the optimal value of a tuning parameter.  Can you provide your candidate form of $\hat f(x;\beta)$ and info on $f(x;\alpha)$? Then I could be more specific.